# C#: is there a way to display result base on user input at the moment

Tags: c#

I am working on a unit converting project. The idea is to develop something like google's converter, except it is in windows application form.
I want the result to show based on user's input at the moment. that means if user is converting 100cm to m, the result will show 0.01m when 1 is typed in and 1m as he completes the input.
Is there a way to doing it? I have been searching in google but all of the helps are on java script.
Thanks!

Comment: if you use textboxes you can do textchanged event

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `KeyUp` event.

Answer (score 0):

Using textchanged event.In this example textbox1 is cm and textbox2 is m:

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
                textBox2.Text = "0";
            else
                textBox2.Text = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text) / 100).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! i am looking into it now